# Spring Session Rest and AuthenticationManager

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

From the Spring Session Rest sample: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/rest.html

I have deployed the sample on Cloud Foundry and it works.
I am wondering how the session is working with Spring Security AuthenticationManager to authenticate the x-auth-token in the second request.
I checked the code in the Spring Session, but not found any details.

To my understanding, the authentication manager will look for the session in the SessionRepository by the x-auth-token.

Can someone show me how the authentication in the Spring Session Rest works?

Comment: Please do not post naked links, use instead the 'Insert Hyperlink' (Ctrl + L).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually as far as Spring Security is concerned there's nothing different in this sample compared to an application that doesn't use Spring Session (i.e. uses Servlet container's internal session storage and JSESSIONID cookie).

Spring Session uses `org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter` to replace Servlet container's `HttpSession` implementation with a custom implementation backed by Spring Session. This filter also provides `HttpSessionStrategy` (either cookie based or, like in your sample, HTTP request header based) to correlate the information your provided (again, either via cookie or header) to the session stored in `SessionRepository` implementation of your choice. After that, it's all up to how your application uses the session.

Note that Spring Security's `AuthenticationManager` simply handles authentication requests for the provided `Authentication` token. It does not have any knowledge of session, or anything else web/Servlet API related.

Comment: Based on the spring session rest sample, the x-auth-token can be included in the header for authentication. The things is for AuthenticationManager, the Authentication from SecurityContextHolder is empty.

Comment: As explained in the answer above, the ` x-auth-token` header is only used to correlate your request with the session persisted on the server, it's not directly tied to the authentication process per se. Please refer to the `SessionRepositoryFilter` source and Javadoc. You can also take a look at [`session-strategy` sample from this repo](https://github.com/vpavic-demos/javacro16-spring-session) as it's much simpler example that does not include Spring Security.

Comment: I checked the Spring Session and Spring Security source code. Spring Session SessionRepositoryFilter will substitute the HttpSession with the Spring Session. SecurityContextPersistenceFilter will do the magic. The first time user will login, Security Context will be generated and stored in Spring Session and save by SecurityContextRepository. Next time user login, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter will load the context from SecurityContextRepository and set in the SecurityContextHolder. Please correct me if that is not the case.

Comment: That is correct. Note that the Spring Security part of the process is completely agnostic of the way the `HttpSession` itself is persisted, and is the same if you use containers default session persistence mechanisms,  as explained in the answer.